# "ValueError: Precision not allowed in integer format specifier" in f-string pops up even when using only floats

Tags: python, valueerror

I'm training a Neural Network, but that's not relevant. The only relevant info is this line:

```
print(f"{it*100/iters}%, Pos: ({Xcg:.4},{Ycg:.4}), Ideal position: ({Xcg:.4},{Xcg**2-Xcg:.4}), Rew: {c_reward:.3}, Ang: {ang:.3}, ε: {self.eps:.3}")
```

where Xcg, Ycg and ang are floats (either 0. or something like 0.5-0.5, which is also a float);

c_reward is calculated with this expression:

```
r = math.exp(-abs(posy-posx**2+posx))*math.sqrt(posx**2+posy**2)*abs(posx)/posx if posx!= 0 else 0
```

and self.eps is calculated using this expression:

```
self.eps = 0.8 + 0.8 * math.exp(-0.001 * self.steps)
```

where steps goes from 0 to 4000. So, eps is also a float.

None of those can possibly be floats. What's going on here? It doesn't happen at a specific value of self.steps either, right now it looks random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see at least one `int` already without seeing all the details, your `else` is for `0` which is an `int`. Need to do `0.0` for a float.

```
r = math.exp(-abs(posy-posx**2+posx))*math.sqrt(posx**2+posy**2)*abs(posx)/posx if posx!= 0 else 0.0
```

Comment: Good catch! That was the problem (well not actually there but your response made me look at other parts of the code I previously thought wouldn't remain active). Thanks